# gRPC unary-streaming continues after disconnect / blocks on interrupt

Tags: python, grpc

I have a simple unary-stream method `Subscribe` which send the most recent item seen by the connected client on a queue. If no new item has been pushed in a second, the most recently seen item is sent again for a heartbeat.

```
class Service(proto_grpc.ServiceServicer):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        self.queue = queue

    def Subscribe(self, request, context):
        index = 0
        state = self.queue.get(index, timeout=None)

        while state:
            temp = self.queue.get(index, timeout=1)
            if temp:
                state = temp
                index = index + 1

            yield state
```

The remaining relevant portion of the program is given below.

```
def main(server, queue):
    server.start()

    try:
        while True:
            queue.append('foo')
        time.sleep(1)
    finally:
        server.stop(None)
```

Logging shows that if a client subscribes and then disconnects (ungracefully), the Subscribe method will continue to process. Each disconnection also seems to be unavailable to new clients.

Also strangely, if the server process is interrupted, then the server is stopped, the client is disconnected, and the server blocks on the `yield` statement.

What is the proper way to deal with ungraceful clients being removed from a streaming RPC?

EDIT: A simplified version of the servicer that displays the same behavior.

```
class Service(proto_grpc.ServiceServicer):
    def Subscribe(self, request, context):
        print 'subscribed'

        while context.is_active():
            time.sleep(1)
            print 'sending'
            yield some_proto_payload
            print 'sent'

        print 'finished'
```

Once connected, 'sending/sent' pairs will be printed regardless of the connection status of the client. When the server stops after a disconnect, output hangs between the last 'sending' and 'sent' messages.

Comment: Should you be making use of the `context.is_active()` method to determine whether or not the RPC that you are servicing is still active?

You may have found a separate bug or two as well; I'll look further.

Comment: I have tried context.is_active(). It did not seem to ever be True on a forceful disconnect, however. I'm currently attempting to reproduce the same behavior using a Golang server, and the stream.Context().Done() channel correctly closes once a write fails.

Comment: Can you say more about what you mean by "the server blocks on the `yield` statement"? Are you seeing something like a blocked thread and the server shutdown hang? Or does the `grpc.Server.stop(None)` method terminate with an ordinary return in after a reasonable period of time? Keep in mind that it is not guaranteed that the application-level response iterator will be called to exhaustion.

Comment: The process does not terminate and the last output printed is the message directly before a send to the client.

Comment: That's surprising. It's not guaranteed that client cancellation or network disconnection is noticed on the server in a timely fashion but it is guaranteed that if the server-side application is emitting response values then those values' failure to reach the client is _eventually_ noticed.

Verify that the `server.stop(None)` method is called? Verify that the `server.stop(None)` method returns (or doesn't)? If you run in a debugger are you able to see which threads are blocked, and where? What happens if rather than `'foo'` you send messages between ten kibibytes and one mebibytes in size?

Comment: When the server is stopped with a disconnected client the `stop` method returns a `threading.Event` object that blocks indefinitely if waited on. I've added a simplified servicer to the original post to clarify some details.

Comment: Thanks for the simplified servicer. There's of course a chance that it will never print `finished` because depending on the timing of the disconnection (and the timing of the server-side runtime's detection of the disconnection) the server-side run-time may simply not call the application-level servicer following the disconnection (see [this nearly-year-old thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/grpc-io/JAwRhBnSDfI/DuSCxQ6ROgAJ) for a lot of detail).

Comment: It's very weird that a call to `server.stop(None)` would return a `threading.Event` that is not already in its "set" state and does not immediately return from `wait` calls. Confirm that that's what you're seeing?

Comment: Does your program output change if you use `logging.warning` rather than `print`? Also with what version of Python are you running, and on what platform?

Comment: I am going to be posting a minimal working example on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/grpc-io/45LxvLyYVLk.

Comment: Let's migrate further investigation to [this issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/11157).

Comment: Did you ever get the answer to your question?

Comment: No, the issue was closed due to inactivity/interest, but other people are providing reproducible examples of the same error. We've abandoned gRPC with python and rewrote the necessary servers in Go as this was a showstopper.

Comment: I can confirm that your gist still fails with Python 3.7.2, futures==3.1.1 and grpcio==1.19.0

Comment: This is still a problem...